# How to access nested array inside a JSON object from javascript

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I am working with a json object that has nested arrays as well as names with spaces such as `Account ID`.  I need to display just the `Account ID`'s in my Vue.js application.  I am able to get my entire `response.data` json object but not too sure how to get just the `Account ID` when it's nested like the example below.

**JSON**

```
"response": {
    "result": {
      "Accounts": {
        "row": [
          {
            "no": "1",
            "FL": [
              {
                "val": "ACCOUNT ID",
                "content": "123456789"
              },
              ...
```

**Vue.js**

```
<script>
        import axios from "axios";
        export default {
            name: 'HelloWorld',
            data () {
                return {
                    accounts: [],
                    accountIDs: []
                }
            },
            mounted() {
              var self = this;
              axios.get('https://MYAPIGETREQUEST')
                .then( function(res){
                    self.accounts = res.data;
                    self.accountIDs = //This is where I want to get the Account ID
                    console.log('Data: ', res.data);
                })
                .catch( function(error){
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: if you know the shape of the json data structure, why can't you access it directly? with es6 destructuring, it's even easier

Comment: I do feel like it should be that simple but not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to display the 'Account ID' in a text area to see if I am grabbing the data but nothing is appearing.  I was trying res.data.response.result.row[0].FL[0].val["ACCOUNT ID'].content, but I know I'm doing something wrong

Comment: what is the result of console.log('Data: ', res.data); ?

Comment: i don't think it's res.data. it should be res.response or res.result

Comment: @jonhid My entire json response object

Comment: You just need to walk down the object structure... https://jsfiddle.net/7jkuhuah/3/

Comment: @codemax the reason I put res.data is because when I do self.accounts = res.data; it DOES display my entire json response object in the text area so I know I am getting data back doing res.data.  I just tried without res.data and doing res.response and still no luck

Comment: @John You were right.  User error of course.  I was missing my extra 'response'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
if(res.data.response.result.Accounts.row[0].FL[0].val === 'ACCOUNT ID') {

   self.accountIDs = res.data.response.result.Accounts.row[0].FL[0].content;

   ...
}
```

Comment: I realized that I was missing part of my data structure. I had res.data.result... but I needed to have res.data.response.result...  However, I do like this solution for additional validation of my response object if I ever need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
let rowAccounts = response.result.Accounts.row
   .map(row => row.FL
       .filter(FL => FL.val === 'ACCOUNT ID')
       .map(acc => acc.content)
    );

self.accountIDs = [].concat.apply([], rowAccounts);
```

In `rowAccounts`, you get and array of accounts array per row like:

```
[
   0: ['acc row 1', 'another acc row1'],
   1: ['acc row 2'....]
]
```

Now it all depends upon your implementation the way you like it.